# nested panels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

first, sorry for my English and mistakes. 
I have a plot like this:

```
data <- data.frame(site=rep(letters[1:6],each=3), year=rep(2001:2003, 6), nb=round(runif(18, min=20, max=60)), group=c(rep("A",9),rep("B", 6),rep("C",3)))

ggplot(data=data, aes(x= factor(year), y= nb)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~site)
```

And I would like to add the other panel "group". In fact I would like to make this graph without empty parts:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x= factor(year), y= nb)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(group~site)
```

Does someone has an idea? Thanks for you help!

#### #

There is this solution which look like that I want, but I thought there were more simple solution :

```
plt1 <- ggplot(data=data[data$group=="A",], aes(x= factor(year), y= nb)) + 
          geom_point() + 
          ggtitle("A")+
          facet_grid(~site)+
          xlab("") + ylab("")

plt2 <- ggplot(data=data[data$group=="B",], aes(x= factor(year), y= nb)) + 
          geom_point() + 
          ggtitle("B")+
          facet_grid(~site)+
          xlab("") + ylab("")

plt3 <- ggplot(data=data[data$group=="C",], aes(x= factor(year), y= nb)) + 
         geom_point() + 
         ggtitle("C")+
         facet_grid(~site)+
         xlab("") + ylab("")

library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(plt1,plt2, plt3),
                         left = textGrob("nb",rot=90))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can combine the `site` and `group` inside the `facet_wrap()` - so you will have only "full" facets.

```
 ggplot(data=data, aes(x= factor(year), y= nb)) + 
     geom_point() + 
     facet_wrap(~site+group)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact I really would like one row for each "group" with the label of group apart.

Comment: Then what should be placed in those combinations of site and group where is no data? How you imagine this plot should look like?

Comment: The default behaviour is drop=TRUE which would remove any blank rows/columns but since there is at least on example of all groups nothing can be removed..This solution (or the default) is the best option.

Comment: In my real data I have city (=site) which are in one geographic frontage (=group) and I would like to classify these sites by frontage, with one row by frontage and sites under it.